# Rewrite rules html/php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have this .htaccess code to remove .php/.html extensions.

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

  # Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 


# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

I am trying to have a page poll.php to be /poll/123123/ <- (6 digit ID) from poll.php?poll=123123.

I tried adding in

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ polls.php?poll=$1 [NC,L]
```

but it then tries to detect dashboard.php instead of dashboard.html.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a wildcard if you're looking for a sp[ecific URL and only the number changes

```
 RewriteRule ^poll/(\d+)/$ polls.php?poll=$1
```

or better to get always 6 digits

```
RewriteRule ^poll/([0-9]{6})/$ polls.php?poll=$1
```

That should do